# Best font size em or px to use for Website and Web apps?

Tags: css, html

I have been searching for em/px value use for web apps and apparently nowadays both are behave same, since the latest browser supports both in same way. My question is, when designing complex web app, having responsive table, grids and charts: what is the best value to use, not only for font size but also for padding/margin/height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremely subjective question. In addition, there are more options than just em and px: rem, em, px, vw/vh. Understanding how they all work is the key to picking which one is best for you and you app depending on the situation. Most of the time I use rem/em for responsive reasons, but there are times with vw/vh or px are a better option for me. It totally depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm comfortable to use em value on fonts. but, I was thinking, if there are nested layout elements and having relative value such as em, create issues when the application grows. Anyway I would take this as answer.

Comment: This is why I tend to use rem over em for most layouts/fonts, as it's easier to make them globally constrained, rather than relatively. You can sometimes utilize em(s) for a more responsive approach, but I've found it's more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Ems are becoming increasingly popular in web documents due to scalability and their mobile-device-friendly nature.
One problem with the pixel unit is that it does not scale upward for visually-impaired readers or downward to fit mobile devices.
That's why i recommend you to use ems in fonts and pixels for blocks

Comment: fonts yes of cause, i doubt on padding, ,margin, height, etc. thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @NPN also use pixels for paddings and margins. cause you use them for blocks, consequently it is recommended to use pixels for blocks even you use percentage for block sizes.